# Nivo responsivebarcanvas chart not working with large dataest

Tags: d3.js, charts, bar-chart, nivo-slider, nivo-react

I am using Responsive bar canvas as it is suggested to use for large datasets. But, it is not working in my case and all the bars are overlapping on each other.

Can anyone please take a look and help if I am missing on something.

Check below link for demo :
[https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-z52uk5?file=src/App.js][1]